# Bootstrap 3 - how to use offsets to get equal spacing between `.col-md-3`

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eLaj3ksb/

Output looks like this:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is get "Column C" to be aligned with the right of the red column, but also keep "Column A" where it is, and have equal spacing between "Column B".

So essentially I want it to appear as it is, with "Column C" on the right and "Column B" in the middle. Equal spacing between Columns A-B and B-C.

I can't figure out which `offset` classes need to be used. I want Column A/B/C to be equal width so have used `col-md-3`. So that adds up to 9. But what `offset` numbers do I use to make this work?

If I use `.col-md-offset-1` on "Column A", "Column C" ends up where I want, but it pushes "Column A" off the left hand side of the red column!

I get the thing of it needs to add up to 12... but how is this possible in this situation?

Are the 5px grey borders on my columns (A/B/C) causing a problem? If so, how can I have such borders and maintain the spacing?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that with standard Bootstrap classes. That's not how Boottrap works.

Comment: Yeah, because I suppose it's like asking for "col-md-1.5" between A-B and B-C, which isn't a thing! That's really limiting though! The content above is within a `.col-md-12` and so it looks like the alignment of the boxes below is off. It looks awful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible (as far as I am aware) with standard Bootstrap3 classes / offsets.

Flexbox can do this but it does mean overriding some of the standard Bootstrap 3 properties.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row.flex:before,
.row.flex:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid red;">
            <div class="row flex">
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border:5px solid #ccc; padding: 20px; min-height: 150px;">
                    <p>Column A</p>
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border:5px solid #ccc; padding: 20px; min-height: 150px;">
                    <p>Column B</p>
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-3" style="border:5px solid #ccc; padding: 20px; min-height: 150px;">
                    <p>Column C</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```